# How does Mithril component work here is some weird experience I had

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I was going through documentation and I ran following code in script.js

```
    var Article = {
    view: function(vnode) {
        console.log(vnode)
        return "This is article " + vnode.attrs.articleid
    }
}
m.route(document.body, '/article/:articleid' ,{
    '/article/:articleid': Article
})
m.route.set('/article/:articleid', {articleid: 1})
```

but to my surprise I got the vnode ds twice in console

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv9WC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because the router executes immediately when it’s defined (when you call `m.route(…)`), and then once again when you call `m.route.set(…)`. The second argument to `m.route(…)` is the route that will resolve immediately, and the call to `m.route.set(…)` isn’t necessary to initialise routing— in this case you’ve kept the route parameter interpolation string, but it should be expressed literally:

```
var Article = {
  view: function(vnode) {
    console.log(vnode)
      return "This is article " + vnode.attrs.articleid
  }
}

m.route(document.body, '/article/1' ,{
    '/article/:articleid': Article
  })
```